# Installation of Socket.io in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, socket.io, 64-bit

I want to install socket.io in ubuntu desktop 64-bit server (14.04).
I tried all the ways and googled alot but couldn't find a way to fix this.
I can't get it work on port 80 with nginx and even can't run it to show the welcome message And the page that gives the connection ID.

can anyone suggest anything?

Best wishes.

Comment: If you have nginx on port 80, then you have to bind node on the another port. In this case your firewall might block connections to this port. Do you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: it's desktop ubuntu and firewall is disabled.

Comment: Do you see errors when you start node server?

Comment: Thanks for ur replys. I get socket working but I can see the page that shows welcome to socket.io or connection id when ever.